# How to resolve "Error(s): Please enter a valid format for "Select"." when creating a Jawbone UP app?

Tags: jawbone

When trying to create my application in the [Jawbone developer portal](https://jawbone.com/up/developer), I get the following error message:

[image: Error(s): Please enter a valid format for "Select"]

I googled the error message and found this [blog post](https://www.sitepoint.com/connecting-jawbone-up-api-node-js/), which says the issue is that my logo is too large. However, my image is under 4k, and the upload itself seems to succeed. The failure only appears after trying to save the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dug into the developer portal code on this one (I am re-posting this question here after receiving an email about it), and it appears that the check is against the file name and not the file size.

Currently uploaded filenames must match this regular expression:

```
/^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[A-Za-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
```

So, any filenames with non-alphanumeric characters will fail.

Definitely need to improve that error message and will review whether this check needs to exist.