# Jawbone Create Application

Tags: jawbone

I am creating an application on jawbone development portal, The problem I am facing is that when i click on 'Create Application' it gives me the error that 'Please enter a valid format for "Select"'. I tried uploading jpg and png formats for logo but the problem is still same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Error(s): Please enter a valid format for "Select"." when creating a Jawbone UP app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354003/how-to-resolve-errors-please-enter-a-valid-format-for-select-when-creati)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to one of the following issues with the image file:

1. The file is too large
2. The filename has unexpected characters

More details in this answer:
[How to resolve "Error(s): Please enter a valid format for "Select"." when creating a Jawbone UP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354003/how-to-resolve-errors-please-enter-a-valid-format-for-select-when-creati)

Comment: The size of my file is 2Kb. Can you give me any filename with expected characters.

Comment: Any .png, .jpg, or .jpeg whose file name is alphanumeric.

Comment: OK let me try this

Comment: kindly help me with this :)

Comment: Please email your image file and your app's client id (the URL from the UP developer portal) to apisupport @ jawbone.com